# Concatenation of dataframes with tuple indices

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

i have a collection of data frames and i want to concatenate them:

```
1            1,1
    (0, 0)  111
    (0, 1)  256
    (1, 0)  252
    (1, 1)  381


2            1,3
    (0, 0)   50
    (0, 1)   85
    (0, 2)  119
    (0, 3)  191
    (1, 0)   88
    (1, 1)  111
    (1, 2)  157
    (1, 3)  199


3            1,4
    (0, 0)   21
    (0, 1)   56
    (0, 2)   88
    (0, 3)  130
    (0, 4)  136
    (1, 0)   67
    (1, 1)   81
    (1, 2)  121
    (1, 3)  138
    (1, 4)  162
```

the result should be something like this:

```
       1,1  1,4  1.3
(0, 0) 111  21   50
(0, 1) 256  56   85
(0, 2) NaN  88   119
(0, 3) NaN 130   191
(0, 4) NaN 136   NaN
(1, 0) 252  67   88
(1, 1) 381  81   111
(1, 2) NaN 121   157
(1, 3) NaN 138   199
(1, 4) NaN 162   NaN
```

i used this to concatenate the collection:

```
df = pd.concat(s_ds)
```

with axis=1 but I get a result with keys separating every element. Could help me in finding a way to merge the collection of dataframe stored in s_ds without the key ?

Comment: Have you tried outer join with df.join?

Comment: i just tried it out df = pd.concat(s_ds, join='outer') but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outer join with `df.join` (still alright if you have 2-3 dataframes):

```
In [262]: df.join(df2, how='outer').join(df3, how='outer')
Out[262]: 
          1,1    1,3  1,4
(0, 0)  111.0   50.0   21
(0, 1)  256.0   85.0   56
(0, 2)    NaN  119.0   88
(0, 3)    NaN  191.0  130
(0, 4)    NaN    NaN  136
(1, 0)  252.0   88.0   67
(1, 1)  381.0  111.0   81
(1, 2)    NaN  157.0  121
(1, 3)    NaN  199.0  138
(1, 4)    NaN    NaN  162
```

Here, `df`, `df2`, and `df3` are your three dataframes.

---

Alternative using `pd.concat` (better for multiple dataframes, like your case):

```
In [278]: df = pd.concat([df, df2, df3], axis=1)

In [279]: df.index = df.index.to_series()

In [280]: df
Out[280]: 
          1,1    1,3  1,4
(0, 0)  111.0   50.0   21
(0, 1)  256.0   85.0   56
(0, 2)    NaN  119.0   88
(0, 3)    NaN  191.0  130
(0, 4)    NaN    NaN  136
(1, 0)  252.0   88.0   67
(1, 1)  381.0  111.0   81
(1, 2)    NaN  157.0  121
(1, 3)    NaN  199.0  138
(1, 4)    NaN    NaN  162
```

Comment: ` df = s_ds[0]

for i in range(2, len(s_ds)):
    df = df.join(s_ds[i], how='outer') `  i used this version because i have a collection of more than 10 dataframe

Comment: @RababAlkhalifa Check my second solution using `pd.concat`. That might also help. You can mark accepted if you wish :)